# Magento how to save custom field in admin panel

Tags: php, magento

In `Manage Products` -> `Edit` a product -> `Images` I've added 2 new columns (which are located in the `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` table).

Those 2 columns are filled every time there is a media import and each field only show the value (you can't enter a new value). It's also used on the frontend.
I've modified in my own theme the correct admin template file and created a new product.js to display the 2 new fields.
So far everything is working as intended.

But whenever a user tries to modify something in the `Images` section, let say the label of an image or the position, my 2 custom fields are not saved and Magento give them the `NULL` value.

Because the 2 new columns are not input fields, I thought Magento would not update it, but looks like it does. I've been trying to find where the label and position are saved for the `Images` section so that I can add my custom values but I can't find it. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Or would it be better to listen to the catalog_product_save_after event and create an observer to save my custom values?

Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it, I missed it during my previous searches. I'll answer it myself just in case it can help someone else. Code is in the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media` class, inside the `afterSave` function.
All you have to do is to rewrite it.

Config.xml should contain the following :

```
<models>
    <catalog_resource>
        <rewrite>
            <product_attribute_backend_media>
                Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media
            </product_attribute_backend_media>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog_resource>
</models>
```

And class should be : `Namespace_Module_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media`